# why char ch =4 (without '') , is not error?

Tags: java

I want to know why char ch =5; (for example)
is not error ? but if I print

```
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(ch));
// output 

false
```

it will be false ?

Comment: Because a `char` is a (16-bit unsigned) number.

Comment: Google "ascii table" and look at some of the images you will get.  "Characters" (such as the things you're reading right now) are each represented by a numeric code.  The number 5 is in the "control code" section and represents the "enquiry" control code (a code that really only makes sense to a 40-year-old Teletype).  The character "5", on the other hand, is represented by a `char` with the value decimal 53.

Comment: This a fundamental question, but not a bad one, and doesn't deserve to be downvoted. Can anyone find where in the docs or JLS it describes this behavior?

Comment: FYI: Casting a `char` as `int` does the reverse of what you're seeing, e.g. `System.out.println((int)'5')` prints `53` (the Unicode value of the 
_character_ `5`).

Comment: Also: contrary to the answers below, `char`s in Java are 16-bit Unicode characters, not ASCII (which are 7- or 8-bit, depending on flavor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character is represented by two bytes in memory. Java converts 5 to a character.
'5' is not the 6th character (its hexadecimal code is 35 and not 5) in the ASCII table and is thus not a "digit".

Comment: Correction -- In Java a character is represented by a 16-bit number.

Answer (score 9):

Because `5` is an integer literal that can be converted to a `char`. It is not the character `'5'` however.

Answer (score 4):

try this example :

```
 char ch = 97;
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ch = "+ch);
```

The answer would be : ch = a

It simply won't give an error even though 97 is without `(' ')` because 97 represent the ASCII code for the character `'a'` so it's not a digit , and that's why you are getting false as a result.

Answer (score 1):

if you give `ch = 5`, it's automatically covert to char based on ASCII value.